# Change line style depending on third variable - R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Following my dataframe, using dput():

```
structure(list(year = 1984:2007, ger.90.10.ratio = c(3.1, 3.09, 
2.98, 2.93, 2.98, 2.96, 2.95, 3.12, 3.16, 3.13, 3.24, 3.3, 3.28, 
3.24, 3.24, 3.17, 3.23, 3.31, 3.63, 3.69, 3.75, 3.91, 4.1, 3.99
), kanzler = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), wahljahr = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), us.90.10.ratio = c(9.55, 9.69, 10.09, 
10.23, 10.21, 9.99, 10.12, 10.22, 10.34, 10.64, 10.57, 10.11, 
10.33, 10.6, 10.44, 10.42, 10.58, 10.63, 10.75, 11.22, 11.08, 
11.17, 11.08, 11.18), us.80.20.ratio = c(4.36, 4.38, 4.49, 4.48, 
4.45, 4.44, 4.42, 4.51, 4.6, 4.65, 4.68, 4.52, 4.61, 4.64, 4.65, 
4.62, 4.56, 4.65, 4.69, 4.83, 4.76, 4.78, 4.84, 4.93), ger.ratio.diff = c(NA, 
-0.0100000000000002, -0.11, -0.0499999999999998, 0.0499999999999998, 
-0.02, -0.00999999999999979, 0.17, 0.04, -0.0300000000000002, 
0.11, 0.0599999999999996, -0.02, -0.0399999999999996, 0, -0.0700000000000003, 
0.0600000000000001, 0.0800000000000001, 0.32, 0.0600000000000001, 
0.0600000000000001, 0.16, 0.19, -0.109999999999999), ger.ratio.change = c(0, 
-0.0100000000000002, -0.11, -0.0499999999999998, 0.0499999999999998, 
-0.02, -0.00999999999999979, 0.17, 0.04, -0.0300000000000002, 
0.11, 0.0599999999999996, -0.02, -0.0399999999999996, 0, -0.0700000000000003, 
0.0600000000000001, 0.0800000000000001, 0.32, 0.0600000000000001, 
0.0600000000000001, 0.16, 0.19, -0.109999999999999)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("year", "ger.90.10.ratio", "kanzler", "wahljahr", 
"us.90.10.ratio", "us.80.20.ratio", "ger.ratio.diff", "ger.ratio.change"
), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is to create a lineplot that changes the line style depending on the value of a third variable.
It should look like the following plot[image: Plot with different line style depending on presidents party affiliation]

In words:
In the above dataframe I would like to plot ger.90.10.ratio against year and change the style of the line depending on the values in the kanzler-column.

I have searched everywhere (maybe my google-fu is bad?) but I'd really like to know if that is possible in R.

Thanks for your help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R's base graphics don't allow for changing line properties (type/dash pattern, colour, etc.) mid-line, so you have to split the data and use `lines()` on the pieces, or `segments()`.

This is not a full solution but it's a start:

Set graphics parameters (unnecessary but I like it):

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
```

Generate a variable for splitting (we want each segment differentiated):

```
dat <- transform(dat,k2=c(0,cumsum(diff(kanzler)!=0)))
```

Split up the data:

```
s <- split(dat,dat$k2)
```

Set up an empty plot:

```
plot(ger.90.10.ratio~year,data=dat,type="n")
```

Add the lines for each piece:

```
invisible(lapply(s,
     function(x) with(x,lines(year,ger.90.10.ratio,col=kanzler))))
```

[image]

You can do this slightly more compactly (as usual) in `ggplot2`, but the `k2` variable we set up is still useful:

```
library("ggplot2")
qplot(year,ger.90.10.ratio,data=dat,colour=factor(kanzler),
      group=k2,geom="line")
```

[image]

Comment: You, Sir, are a champion. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This a solution using `lattice` package to show how much it is similar to base graphics plots. I am basically using @Ben idea of splitting the data. I use`lattice` panel to give a more `compact` solution.

[image]

```
library(lattice)
dat <- transform(dat,k2=c(0,cumsum(diff(kanzler)!=0)))
s <- split(dat,dat$k2)
xyplot(ger.90.10.ratio~year,data=dat,type=c('p'),groups=kanzler,
       main = 'THE PARTISAL POLITICAL ECONOMY',
       auto.key=list(columns=2,cex=2,text=c('Democrats','Republicans')),
       panel=function(x,y,...) {
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         lapply(s,function(x) 
          with(x,panel.lines(year,ger.90.10.ratio,col=kanzler)))
         panel.grid()
       })
```